# 2D Scrollable View with Matrix of Numbers on Android

Tags: android

I would like to implement a 2D, scrollable view which can be scrolled horizontally, vertically or even diagonally (similar to a zoomed image which can be scrolled in any direction, but has bounds). In that scroll view, I would like to have matrix of numbers. Which component(s) should I use for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: How does this relate to game development? I believe this is a question better suited for StackOverflow. (As a side suggestion, I would use a [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) )

Comment: posted the same in StackOverflow but didn't get anything much. Tried with extending view class and implemented GestureDetector but the scroll is not smooth. Hope this community can help.

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't make it on-topic here, see [help] if you'd like to read the specific guidelines. That said, I really recommend you experiment with Grid view and play with the samples provided in the Android SDK, I've made something very similar and it took a good bit of tweaking to get it to work.

Comment: I could see this having all sorts of relation to game development for all manner of puzzle games or puzzle elements inside a different type of game.  I definitely wouldn't consider this off topic.